# DB with best inserts/sec performance?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, postgresql, mongodb

We deploy an (AJAX - based) Instant messenger which is serviced by a Comet server.  We have a requirement to store the sent messages in a DB for long-term archival purposes in order to meet legal retention requirements.

Which DB engine provides the best performance in this write-once, read never (with rare exceptions) requirement?

We need at least 5000 Insert/Sec. I am assuming neither MySQL nor PostgreSQL
can meet these requirements.

Any proposals for a higher performance solution? HamsterDB, SQLite, MongoDB ...?

Comment: I'm in the process of restructuring some application into mongoDB.
You forgot CouchDB in your list, but from what I've learned, I'd opt for mongoDB as well...

Comment: Thanks, means I would be with MongoDB on the right way, any more Votes for MongoDB? :-)

Comment: In my no-so-recent tests, I achieved 14K tps with MySQL/Innodb on the quad-core server and throughput was cpu-bound in python, not mysql. In other words your assumption about MySQL was quite wrong. My transactions were quite simple test-and-insert with contention, think "King of the Hill" played between many users.

Comment: A DB is the correct solution if you need data coherency, keyed access, fail-over, ad-hoc query support, etc. Your problem has none of these requirements. Therefore a DB is a poor choice. There are Open Source solutions for logging that are free or low cost, but at your performance level writing the data to a flat-file, probably in a comma-delimited format, is the best option. JSON, or any key-value pair format will about double the storage requirement, and be massively redundant as the keys will be repeated millions of times.

Comment: I have seen 100KB Insert/Sec with gce mysql 4CPU memory 12GB and 200GB ssd disk.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you are never going to query the data, then i wouldn't store it to a database at all, you will never beat the performance of just writing them to a flat file.

What you might want to consider is the scaling issues, what happens when it's to slow to write the data to a flat file, will you invest in faster disk's, or something else.

Another thing to consider is how to scale the service so that you can add more servers without having to coordinate the logs of each server and consolidate them manually.

edit: You wrote that you want to have it in a database, and then i would also consider security issues with havening the data on line, what happens when your service gets compromised, do you want your attackers to be able to alter the history of what have been said?

It might be smarter to store it temporary to a file, and then dump it to an off-site place that's not accessible if your Internet fronts gets hacked.

Comment: This is a reason more for a DB System, most of them will help to be able to scale them without troubles. At the moment my favorite is MongoDB but I'm wondering if another DB System can provide more Insert/sec

Comment: really, log files with log rotation is a solved art.

reliable database scaling is only solved at high price end of the market, and even then my personal experience with it suggests its usually misconfigured and not working properly.

Flat files will be massively faster, always.

Comment: old, but top 5 result in google.. I'm considering this on a project at the moment, similar setup.. dont forget, a database is just a flat file at the end of the day as well, so as long as you know how to spread the load.. locate and access your own storage method.. Its a very viable option.. So i have to agree with the above statement. Common practice now is to store JSON data, that way you can serialize and easily access structured information. Databases have their place, but if your doing an archive... this is the way to do it.

Comment: +1 on using a flat file, which at the end of the day is just a file lacking an index or meta-data visa-vie a DB. You MUST be able to read the archive or fail the legal requirement. I'd RX writing [primary key][rec_num] to a memory-mapped file you can qsort() for an index. The idea is to have an archival file and it's index written to for a specific time period, Eg: 24hrs, and then open a new pair of files for the next period. Once T0 is being written to, qsort() the index for T-1. Performance with RAID of 4xSSDs ~ 2GBs divided by record size. Avg of 256 chars allows 8,388,608 inserts/sec.

Comment: Once you're writing onto the pair of T0 files, and your qsort() of the T-1 index is complete, you can 7-Zip the pair of T-1 files to save space. This problem is almost ENTIRELY dependent on I/O bandwidth.

Comment: Speaking of Zipping the archive file, for max performance make the records a uniform size. To find the 10,000,000th record, if you know the record size, you just seek to the file position calculated as (record size * record number) and be done with it. Otherwise you're going to have to scan through every record in the file to get there, or do a lot of work to keep track of where records start while writing the archive file and index file simultaneously. Add a preamble to each record comprising an array of varchar lengths if needed. 7-Zip will reclaim unused white space for you.

Comment: I think this comment about flat file is wrong, and even for several reasons. First, "flat file" is single file and we can speed that up by writing to several files at once, on several machines, and this is already a more complex system than a flat file. Second, when writing to a filesystem we will have to solve contention problems between different possible concurrent writers (no one said there is but one writer), again it's more complex than simply writing to a file. Third, we can use inmemory data storage, totally avoiding disk writes, how about that?

Answer (score 43):

Please ignore the above Benchmark we had a bug inside.

We have Insert 1M records with following columns: id (int), status (int), message (140 char, random). 
All tests was done with C++ Driver on a Desktop PC i5 with 500 GB Sata Disk.

Benchmark with **MongoDB**:

1M Records Insert **without Index**

```
time: 23s, insert/s: 43478
```

1M Records Insert **with Index** on Id

```
time: 50s, insert/s: 20000
```

next we add 1M records to the same table with Index and 1M records

```
time: 78s, insert/s: 12820
```

that all result in near of 4gb files on fs.

Benchmark with **MySQL**:

1M Records Insert **without Index**

```
time: 49s, insert/s: 20408
```

1M Records Insert **with Index**

```
time: 56s, insert/s: 17857
```

next we add 1M records to the same table with Index and 1M records

```
time: 56s, insert/s: 17857
```

exactly same performance, no loss on mysql on growth

We see Mongo has eat around 384 MB Ram during this test and load 3 cores of the cpu, MySQL was happy with 14 MB and load only 1 core.

Edorian was on the right way with his proposal, I will do some more Benchmark and I'm sure we can reach on a 2x Quad Core Server 50K Inserts/sec.

I think MySQL will be the right way to go.

Comment: Wow...these are great stats. May I ask though, were these bulk inserts or...?

Comment: This tells me nothing about whether these were concurrent inserts, if bulk operations were used, or what the state of the caches were. A minute long benchmark is nearly useless, especially when comparing two fundamentally different database types.

Comment: We just hit 28,000/s mixed inserts & updates in MySQL when posting json to php api. Included in time is authentication, 2 queries to determine whether incoming data should be insert or update and determine columns to include in statements. Incoming data was 2000 rows of about 30 columns for customer data table. Tested using Apache Benchmark, 2000 requests, 100 concurrent. Specs : 512GB ram, 24 core, 5 SSD RAID

Comment: This really appears an old answer. Now a days NoSQLs (e.g. MongoDB) are leading.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447034/which-nosql-database-is-best-for-high-volume-inserts-writes

Answer (score 12):

If you don't need to do queries, then database is not what you need. Use a log file.

Comment: I found we can handle the data easier with a DB System, we don't query the data for our web app but if there is some investigation from the law we need to be able to deliver the requested data, means it will use less time to collect it.

Comment: I'd go for a text-file based solution as well. To search them you can use commandline tools like grep or simple text processing. The time you spent into scaling a DBMS for this job will be much more than writing some small scripts to analyze the logfiles, especially if you have a decently structured logfile. 

If it's for legal purposes: a text file on a CD/DVD will still be readable in 10 years (provided the disk itself isn't damaged) as well, are you sure your database dumps will be?

Comment: Understand the tradeoff. The last query might happen once, or not at all. How much time do you want to spend optimizing for it, considering you might not even know the exact request? It's often feasible and legally reasonable to have all necessary data, and manually query it when a police request arrives.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I understand youre point of view, but I'm ready to maintain a DBMS for the benefit that we can easy collect data from it if needed.
@MSalters - That's correct, but to query a DB depending on the request is easier for me then to grep some log files.

Answer (score 5):

> it's only stored for legal reasons.

And what about the detailed requirements? You mention the NoSQL solutions, but these can't promise the data is realy stored on disk. In PostgreSQL everything is transaction safe, so you're 100% sure the data is on disk and is available. (just don't turn of fsync)

Speed has a lot to do with your hardware, your configuration and your application. PostgreSQL can insert thousands of record per second on good hardware and using a correct configuration, it can be painfully slow using the same hardware but using a plain stupid configuration and/or the wrong approach in your application. A single INSERT is slow, many INSERT's in a single transaction are much faster, prepared statements even faster and COPY does magic when you need speed. It's up to you.

Comment: 100% sure on disk might not be necessary for legal reasons. If you can prove you had a disk crash, and specifically because of that can't comply with a particular legal request, that crash can be considered an Act of God.

Comment: Who knows. But an act of God? Would be a nice statement in court, but a good chance you loose. Just check the requirements and than find a solution.

Comment: @Frank Heikens - The data is from a IM of a dating site, there is no need to store it transaction safe. Sure I hope we don't will loss any data. As our budget is limited, we have for this comet server on one deidacted box who will handle the IM conversations and on the same we will store the data. I know the benefits of PostgreSQL but in this actual scenario i think it can not match the performance of MongoDB untill we spend many bucks for a 48 core server, ssd array and much ram.

Comment: @Frank Heikens: Unless you're working in a regulated industry, there won't be strict requirements on log retention. In that case the legal norm can be summarized as "what reasonable people do in general". You could even point to SO for what's considered reasonable.

Comment: And Cassandra will make sure your data is really stored on disc, on more than one host synchronously, if you ask it to.

Comment: "You mention the NoSQL solutions, but these can't promise the data is [really] stored on disk." - NoSQL has nothing to do with whether or not the data is stored on the disk. I'm sure some databases can be setup to delay writing to disk, or not write to disk at all, but others will commit the transaction immediately.

Comment: "In PostgreSQL everything is transaction safe, so you're 100% sure the data is on disk and is available." - Haha, nope. Even with fsync, two phase commits can leave you in an indeterminate state in the event of a network issue between the commit and ack phases.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why you would rule out MySQL. It could handle high inserts per second. If you really want high inserts, use the BLACK HOLE table type with replication. It's essentially writing to a log file that eventually gets replicated to a regular database table. You could even query the slave without affecting insert speeds.

Comment: The Benchmark I have do showed me that MySQL is really a serious RDBMS.

Comment: The BLACKHOLE storage engine acts as a “black hole” that accepts data but throws it away and does not store it. Retrievals always return an empty result:

Comment: That's why you setup replication with a different table type on the replica. Replication then acts as a buffer, though replag will occur.

Answer (score 4):

Firebird can easily handle 5000 Insert/sec if table doesn't have indices.

Comment: I can get 5000 inserts/sec with MongoDB

Answer (score 3):

Depending in your system setup MySql can easily handle over 50.000 inserts per sec.

For tests on a current system i am working on we got to over 200k inserts per sec. with 100 concurrent connections on 10 tables (just some values).

Not saying that this is the best choice since other systems like couch could make replication/backups/scaling easier but dismissing mysql solely on the fact that it can't handle so minor amounts of data it a little to harsh.

I guess there are better solutions (read: cheaper, easier to administer) solutions out there.

Comment: Can you tell me your hardware spec of your current system?

Comment: I can't tell you the exact specs (manufacturer etc.) but in general it's a 8core, 16gb ram machine with a attached storage running ~8-12 600gb drives with a raid 10

Comment: I know this is old but if you are still around...were these bulk inserts?

Comment: Single insert queries

Answer (score 2):

Use Event Store (https://eventstore.org), you can read (https://eventstore.org/docs/getting-started/which-api-sdk/index.html) that when using TCP client you can achieve 15000-20000 writes per second. If you will ever need to do anything with data, you can use projections or do the transformations based on streams to populate any other datastore you wish.
You can create even cluster.

Answer (score 0):

If money plays no role, you can use TimesTen. 
http://www.oracle.com/timesten/index.html

A complete in memory database, with amazing speed.

Comment: I forget to mention we're on a low budget :-)

Comment: Eh, if you want an in-memory solution then save your $$. Use something like mysql but specify that the tables use the MEMORY storage engine, and then set up a slave server to replicate the memory tables to an un-indexed myisam table. problem solved, and $$ saved.

Comment: Last time i was try to do something smiliar i get trouble with record limitation on the Memory table, but the biggest problem was the performance lack with lock/unlock of this table when is used with multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the log file for this, but if you must use a database, I highly recommend [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org). I just tested the speed, it inserts about 10k records per second on quite average hardware (3 years old desktop computer). The table has one compound index, so I guess it would work even faster without it:

```
milanb@kiklop:~$ fbexport -i -d test -f test.fbx -v table1 -p **
Connecting to: 'LOCALHOST'...Connected.
Creating and starting transaction...Done.
Create statement...Done.
Doing verbatim import of table: TABLE1
Importing data...
SQL: INSERT INTO TABLE1 (AKCIJA,DATUM,KORISNIK,PK,TABELA)  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
Prepare statement...Done.
Checkpoint at: 1000 lines.
Checkpoint at: 2000 lines.
Checkpoint at: 3000 lines.
...etc.
Checkpoint at: 20000 lines.
Checkpoint at: 21000 lines.
Checkpoint at: 22000 lines.

Start   : Thu Aug 19 10:43:12 2010
End     : Thu Aug 19 10:43:14 2010
Elapsed : 2 seconds.
22264 rows imported from test.fbx.
```

Firebird is open source, and completely free even for commercial projects.

Comment: I'm not really up-to-date with RDBMS Systems, but last time around 4 years before when i touch Firebird it was the slowest RDBMS available for Inserts. If I'm not wrong MongoDB is around 5 times faster for Inserts then firebird.

Comment: Firebird is a nice DBMS, but _if_ you go for a DBMS, I'd choose PostgreSQL over Firebird any time. The PostgreSQL's community is more active than Firebird's and has plannable release cycles. The biggest drawback of Firebird is the unstructured manual. If you need to find a specific feature/function you need to first go through the Interbase manuals, and then through each(!) of the release notes since then. There is no complete and consolidated manual for the current release, which is very annoying

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer will as well depend on hard disk type (SSD or not) and also the size of the data you insert. I was inserting a single field data into MongoDB on a dual core Ubuntu machine and was hitting over 100 records per second. I introduced some quite large data to a field and it dropped down to about 9ps and the CPU running at about 175%! The box doesn't have SSD and so I wonder if I'd have gotten better with that.

I also ran MySQL and it was taking 50 seconds just to insert 50 records on a table with 20m records (with about 4 decent indexes too) so as well with MySQL it will depend on how many indexes you have in place.