# Which noSQL database is best for high volume inserts / writes?

Tags: mongodb, neo4j, redis, couchdb, nosql

Which nosql system is better equipped for handling high volume inserts out of the box?
Preferably, running on 1 physical machine (many instances allowed).

Has anyone done any benchmarks? (googling did not help)

***Note**: I understand that choosing noSQL database depends on what kind of data needs to be stored (document:MongoDB, graph:Neo4j, etc.).*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Apache Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) is great in write operations, thanks to its unique persistence model. Some claim that it writes about 20 times faster than it reads but I believe it's really dependent on your usage profile.

Read about it in [their FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ#reads_slower_writes) and in [various](https://web.archive.org/web/20111113073349/http://devblog.seomoz.org/2011/11/cassandra-in-production-things-we-learned/) [blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20110627063310/http://www.acunu.com/blogs/richard-low/cassandra-under-heavy-write-load-part-i/) [posts](http://www.mikeperham.com/2010/03/13/cassandra-internals-writing/).

That is, of course, if you have "classical" DB profile of large amounts of data. If your data is small, or is used temporarily and/or as a cache layer, then of course  opt for Redis which has the fastest throughput both for reads and for writes, since it's memory-based (with eventual disk persistence).

Answer (score 16):

If you want fast write speed, you can just insert your data into memory and flush data to the disc at a background every minute or so. That should be fastest solution.

MongoDB and Redis do this actually. For example, in mongodb you can go without journal enabled and writes will be very fast. But keep in mind that if you store data in memory at a single server there is possibility to loose your data (data that not flushed to the disc yet) when your server goes down.

In general, what database to use highly depends on data you want to store and task you are trying to solve.

Comment: In-memory storage with later persistence or simply using MQ would be my first choice as well (+1). But I'm more interested in DB that is better out of the box, so that the system can be maintained by less experienced system administrator (reducing maintenance cost).
Thanks for the tip re "mongodb with disabled journal".

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with a complex object model for inserts your best option is an object database like Versant's:

http://www.versant.com/vision/The_Magic_Cube.aspx

Answer (score 1):

According to my benchmarks, Cassandra is better than MongoDB on large arrays, but MongodDB is more flexible.

Comment: Can you please clarify the meaning of "more flexible"?

Comment: Data modle is more flexible. Cassandra seems do not support List<T>,I have to serialize them to byte. And configuring cassandra is more difficult,mongodb is simple compared.According to my experience, MongoDB is better for new users of NOSQL