# Idea for handle more insertion at a time

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, architecture, redis

I am doing a booking site using **PHP** and **MySql** where i will get lots of data for insertion for a single insertion. Means if i get 1000 booking at a time i will be very slow. So what i am thinking to dump those data in **MongoDb** and run task to save in **MySql**. Also i am thing to use **Redis** for caching most viewed data.

Right now i am directly inserting in db.

Please suggest any one has any idea/suggestion about it.

Answer (score 2):

In pure insert terms, it's REALLY hard to outrun MySQL...  It's one of the fastest pure-append engines out there  (that flushes consistently to disk).

1000 rows is nothing in MySQL insert performance.  If you are falling at all behind, reduce the number of secondary indexes.

Here's a pretty useful benchmark:  https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/05/16/benchmarking-single-row-insert-performance-on-amazon-ec2/, showing 10,000-25,000 inserts individual inserts per second.

Here is another comparing MySQL and MongoDB:  [DB with best inserts/sec performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519972/db-with-best-inserts-sec-performance)

Comment: when it required Sharding?