# C# - Mysql insert limit

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm new in programming and databases. I've started learning Mysql and C#. So, I created a really simple test program in C# to test how many inserts can do in a minute. (Just a simple infinite loop to insert a simple text into a column) I am watching the dashboard in MySQL Workbench and the problem is that the program can only insert 1000 queries/second. If I run 2-3 instances of the program at the same time, I can see 2-3 * 1000 queries/second.
Is there any limit in MySQL?

Comment: "Depending in your system setup MySql can easily handle over 50.000 inserts per sec." - I found this statement here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519972/db-with-best-inserts-sec-performance.
 Please give us an example of how you insert the data, e.g. c# code snippet

Comment: I believe that's a limitation of the program related to the performance of your computer, running more instances of the program of course uses more memory and CPU. Large databases compute way more than 1000 queries per second... I suggest using more threads in your application

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in limit to insert rates.

Lots of things come into play when you're trying for high insert rates. For example.

1. How big is each row you're inserting?
2. How complex are the indexes on your target table? Index updates take time during INSERT operations.
3. Which access method does your table use? MyISAM is transactionless, so a naive program can push more rows/sec. InnoDB has transactions, so doing your inserts in batches of 1000 or so, wrapped in BEGIN / COMMIT statements, can speed things up.
4. How fast are the disks / ssds on your server? How much RAM does it have?
5. How fast are your client machines and the network between them and the MySQL server?
6. Are other programs trying to read the target table at the same time you're doing inserts?

You've mentioned that your total insert rate scales up approximately linearly for 2-3 instances of your insert program. That means the bottleneck is in your insert program, not the server, at that scale.

C#, like many language frameworks, offers *prepared statements*. They are a way to write a query once and use it over and over with different data values. It's faster. It's also safer if your data comes from an untrusted source (look up SQL injection).

MySQL lets you insert multiple rows with a single INSERT operation. Faster.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE tbl (a, b, c)
               VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)
```

MySQL offers the LOAD DATA INFILE statement. You can get astonishingly high bulk load rates with that statement if you need them..